# PHP - How to count all the values of an array with limited ranges?

Tags: php, arrays, cluster-computing, frequency

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(10,25,47,14,45,58,25,29,15,36,45,15,25,27,34);
```

is there a way to output a new array of 10 ranges with key that tells me which is used and frequency as values?

```
$result = array(
    [x0] => frequency // number of values <= x0
    [x1] => frequency // number of values > x0 and <=1
    etc..., [x2], ...., [x7], x[8]
    [x9] => frequency  // number of values >= x9
    )
```

Comment: Sure. You can write some code to calculate all of that.

Comment: Run a series of array_filters, one for each criteria, and count the results of each; or just use array_count_values() if you want individual value counts

Comment: This question is Unclear and Too Broad (seemingly no research and no posted code).  This is a poorly expressed requirement dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for 10 equal segments

```
    $array = array(10,25,47,14,45,58,25,29,15,36,45,15,25,27,34);

    $step = (max($array) - min($array)) / 10;

    $result = [];
    for ($i = min($array); $i < max($array) - $step; $i += $step) {
        $res = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($i, $step) {
            return ($i <= $v) && $v < $i +$step;
        });
        $result[$i . '-' . ($i + $step)] = $res;
    }
```

Return:

```
  "10 - 14.8" => 2
  "14.8 - 19.6" => 2
  "19.6 - 24.4" => 0
  "24.4 - 29.2" => 5
  "29.2 - 34" => 0
  "34 - 38.8" => 2
  "38.8 - 43.6" => 0
  "43.6 - 48.4" => 3
  "48.4 - 53.2" => 0
  "53.2 - 58" => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_count_values()` to count values

```
$array = array(10,25,47,14,45,58,25,29,15,36,45,15,25,27,34);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($vals);
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
    [10] => 1
    [25] => 3
    [47] => 1
    [14] => 1
    [45] => 2
    [58] => 1
    [29] => 1
    [15] => 2
    [36] => 1
    [27] => 1
    [34] => 1
)
```

Comment: Perhaps change variable name $vals to $frequencies.

Comment: @Manjeet Barnala There are more than 10 ranges.

Comment: This is half an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used an array for the range boundaries.  Here with an example of 4 irregular ranges.  And dumped the sorted array to make it easier to see if the results are as you'd expect.

```
<?php
$array  = array(10,25,47,14,45,58,25,29,15,36,45,15,25,27,34);
$bounds = array(0,10,25,50,100);
$lower  = array_shift($bounds);
$range_frequencies = array();
sort($array);
var_dump($array);
foreach($bounds as $upper) {
    $range_frequencies[$lower . '-' . $upper] = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if($v > $lower && $v <= $upper) {
            $range_frequencies[$lower . '-' . $upper]++;
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    $lower = $upper;
}
var_dump($range_frequencies);
```

Output:

```
array (size=15)
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 14
  2 => int 15
  3 => int 15
  4 => int 25
  5 => int 25
  6 => int 25
  7 => int 27
  8 => int 29
  9 => int 34
  10 => int 36
  11 => int 45
  12 => int 45
  13 => int 47
  14 => int 58
array (size=4)
  '0-10' => int 1
  '10-25' => int 6
  '25-50' => int 7
  '50-100' => int 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on Manjeet Barnala's answer:

```
$array = array(10,25,47,14,45,58,25,29,15,36,45,15,25,27,34);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
arsort($vals);
$vals = array_slice($vals,0,10,true);

var_dump($vals);
```

Comment: it's idea but the array key  is an index not value range
 `array(10) 
 [0] =>
 int(3)
 [1] =>
 int(2)
 [2] =>
 int(2)
 [3] =>
 int(1)
 [4] =>
 int(1)
 [5] =>
 int(1)
 [6] =>
 int(1)
 [7] =>
 int(1)
 [8] =>
 int(1)
 [9] =>
 int(1)`